# PowerShell: store Out-String results formatted in an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, formatting, powershell-5.1

I have a script that is looking for some values in xml-like files:

```
$path = "C:\Users\*.xml"
Get-ChildItem $path |
    Select-String -Pattern "<status>", "<logicalIdentifier>" | Out-File out.txt
```

The result is:

[image]

I am trying to store these in an array, however nothing happens (no error message on the console but nothing is printed either):

```
$path = "C:\Users\*.xml"

Get-ChildItem $path |
    Select-String -Pattern "<status>", "<logicalRecordIdentifier>" | 

Foreach-Object {
        $id, $status = $_.Matches[0].Groups['<logicalIdentifier>', '<status>'].Value
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            ID = $id
            Status = $status      
        }
    }
```

I know it's a long shot, but not sure what goes wrong.
Originally the XML file has the following sructure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ACKReceipt xmlns="http://www.test.eu/ReceiptSchema_V1.xsd">
    <receiptTimestamp>2021-04-23T20:32:09.239Z</receiptTimestamp>
    <product>
        <type>LXGF-H78</type>
    </product>
    <receiptType>validation</receiptType>
    <validationReceipt>
        <reportedFilename>filename1</reportedFilename>
        <globalReceiptItem>
            <logicalIdentifier>4567-YYYMMDD</logicalIdentifier>
            <status>Accepted</status>
        </globalReceiptItem>
    </validationReceipt>
</ACKReceipt>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for your xml structure:

```
Clear-Host
$path = "C:\tmp\xml\*.xml"
$foundFiles = Get-ChildItem $path
$arrayTable = $null
$arrayTable = @()
foreach($file in $foundFiles) {
    $file.FullName
    [xml]$fileXML = Get-Content $file | Select-Object -Skip 1
    $currentLogicalIdentifier = $fileXML.ACKReceipt.validationReceipt.globalReceiptItem.logicalIdentifier
    $currentStatus = $fileXML.ACKReceipt.validationReceipt.globalReceiptItem.status
    $arrayTable += new-object psobject -property @{Status=$currentStatus;LogicalIdentifier=$currentLogicalIdentifier;File=$file.Name}
}
# Report to csv file
$arrayTable | Export-Csv -Path "C:\tmp\xml\report.csv" -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation -Encoding "UTF8"
```

Here is how it looks like in eviroment table:

[image]

You can easy export it as csv file as a report.

Comment: I could not read the xml file this way, that's why I tried to reach out for another method. I updated my original question with a sample xml, but changing the XPath accordingly still delivers an empty report

Comment: @PSrookie My answer has been updated. It works now with your xml structure.

Comment: This indeed worked, thank you! Do you know why this one worked while the first xml parsing approach didn't?